# Changing value of String in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, avr

I am currently trying to change the value of a string in the AVR assembly language. I am not sure if it is possible. I declare the string as:

```
message: .db "Frequency = 1 kHz",0x00
```

I am trying to alter the value stored at message later in the code to "Frequency = 2 kHz"
Any idea how to do this? I want to replace the entire string, but still store it at message.

I'm using the AVR assembly language.

I tried doing:

```
message: .db "Frequency = 2 kHz",0x00
```

at a later point in my program, but I realized it would not let me re-initialize the variable.

Comment: Lots of ideas. What assembly language? What have you tried?

Comment: You haven't specified whether you just want to replace a character in a string where you already know the position of the character(s) to replace, or if you also need to search the string for if/where to place the new character(s).

Answer (score 1):

The label "message:" is not a variable. It acts like an address which you can reference elsewhere in your program. From the [manual](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1022.pdf):

> The DB directive reserves memory resources in the program memory or
>   the EEPROM memory. In order to be able to refer to the reserved
>   locations, the DB directive should be preceded by a label.

So it is not in SRAM, where variables reside.

You can use the LPM instruction to load values from the string after first setting Z to contain the address. [LPM : Load Program Memory : R0 ← (Z)]

It sounds like you might want to do something like having two strings and insert the number as character when you need it.

```
message1: .db "Frequency = ",0x00
message2: .db " kHz",0x00
```

You will have to do something to make sure the null byte in the first string is not transmitted.

The character for val = 1 or 2 is just `0x30 + val`